# Can't set Interval on function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

This is the function I am calling:

```
refreshServices() {
this.services = this.monitorService.getServices(); }
```

I call in the constructor, like this:

```
constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
public monitorService: MonitorService) {
this.refreshServices(); }
```

And this works fine, but when i do this:

```
constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
public monitorService: MonitorService) {
setInterval(this.refreshServices,100000); }
```

Doesn't work... This is the error message in console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getServices' of undefined

So, any thoughs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `setInterval` calls passed function in another context where `this` inside the function refers to a global object (`window`) and not to a class from which `setInterval` is called. This means when this line is executed

```
this.monitorService.getServices();
```

it equals to the following

```
window.monitorService.getServices();
```

Since `window` doesn't have `monitorService` property initialized you have that error. To fix this problem you need to bind function's context to the current class

```
//this code ensures that "this" inside "refreshServices" will refer to the class instance
setInterval(this.refreshServices.bind(this),100000);
```

Another possible solution is using arrow function which uses context of enclosing scope

```
refreshServices = () => {
    this.services = this.monitorService.getServices(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use arrow function to resolve your problem.
Seem you need this code below:

```
refressToken() {
this.checkRefreshTokenThread = setInterval(() => {
  const expiredTime = this.authStore.getExpiredTimeLocalStorage();
  const nowTime = String(new Date().getTime());
  const nowTimeJava = Number(nowTime.substr(0, 10));
  this.timeOfRefresh = (expiredTime - nowTimeJava) < CONSTANT._9MINUTES;
  this.isExpired = expiredTime < nowTimeJava;
  if (this.isExpired) {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }else if (this.timeOfRefresh && !this.authStore.getIsReadyLocalStorage()) {
     this.authStore.setIsReadyLocalStorage('true');
  }
}, CONSTANT._1MINUTE);
```

}

After get data from service you should clear interval as below:

```
  clearIntervalRefreshToken() {
clearInterval(this.checkRefreshTokenThread);
```

}

Hope that useful for you!